# (Android) Different Coordinates on Different Resolution How to Fix?

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates

I am making a game that the user should Identify the parts of the face of a person. and I should get the coordinates touched on the image,., but I have tried it on different phones / resolution, but I get the different coordinates. how to fix it guys? please I really need help with this

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but I had success by doing

```
double windowWidth = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
double windowHeight = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
float xDensity = event.getX();
double x = (xDensity / windowWidth) * 100;
float yDensity = event.getY();
double y = (yDensity / windowHeight) * 100;
```

The `* 100` isn't necessary; I just have that for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The image should be constructed of different drawable Views, that you can grab the pressed state of.

If you where to use a static image then you cannot use a coordinate system (based on px) because phones and other Android devices do not have the same screen size. Your other option in that way would be to use dip (density independent pixels) instead of px.